# Does the War Machine Armor have any form of AI in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, war-machine

Does the War Machine Armor have any AI? I know it has a basic HUD, but we never see Rhodes get any AI feedback. If he doesn't, then how does he get anything done? It seems like Tony wouldn't be able to operate the suit very well without JARVIS, and later FRIDAY.

Comment: See here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143003/is-the-war-machine-armour-simply-the-iron-man-armour-with-big-guns?rq=1

Comment: Also here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35418/how-essential-is-jarvis-to-the-iron-man-war-machine-armors?rq=1

Comment: Regarding that last sentence - Tony had a nanny till he was 14, and you're talking about operating a suit?